# @javascriptinterface on Android lower then 4.2 version

Tags: android

I use [D3SView](https://github.com/LivotovLabs/3DSView) library in my app in payment process. It uses `@javascriptinterface` in one of functions. Can I use it on Android >= 2.3 ? [link](https://github.com/LivotovLabs/3DSView/blob/master/3DSView/src/main/java/eu/livotov/labs/android/d3s/D3SView.java) to required class.

code:

```
addJavascriptInterface(new D3SJSInterface(), JavaScriptNS);
```

...

```
class D3SJSInterface   {

 D3SJSInterface(){}

 @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
 public void processHTML(final String paramString) {

        completeAuthorization(paramString);
 }
}
```

How to make this code allowable for >= 2.3 android version?

Comment: Look at the documentation for that annotation:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use it on Android >= 2.3 ?

Yes, though your `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., "build target" in Eclipse) will need to be API Level 17 or higher. On the older devices, the annotation is ignored.

Comment: we got error while compilation on our build server: "cannot find symbol
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
                       ^
  symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
  location: package android.webkit "

Comment: @StasShakirov: Presumably, your `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., `target` in `project.properties`) is not set to API Level 17 or higher.